# Importing .sas into SAS as text

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

Is there a way to import the actual code of a .sas file into SAS without changing the base file to a .txt. I’m trying to make a tool to search through lines of code for certain keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`infile`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) statement:

```
filename sastext "\test.sas";

data sastext;
   infile sastext truncover;
   input str $32000.;
run;

filename sastext clear;
```

test.sas:

```
data _null_;
   put "TEST";
run;
```

dataset sastext:

```
+-----------------+
|       str       |
+-----------------+
| data _null_;    |
| put "TEST";     |
| run;            |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: What happened to leading spaces?

Comment: @data_null_ it's interesting question. [Here](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0144370.htm) written: _Because list input interprets a blank as a delimiter, use modified list input to read values that contain blanks_

Comment: You are not using LIST input you are using FORMATTED input.  For this task I would think you want to preserve leading blanks using $CHAR or $VARYING in-formats.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, was using file path instead of file name